# Executing a program in a windows uninstaller

Tags: windows, nsis, uninstallation

I am using NSIS to create a Windows installer. In my **uninstaller** I need to execute a different program just before I exit (no need to wait for that program to finish before exiting).

After running the uninstaller from Windows control panel I get the following problem: The list is not refreshed until I manually refresh it and even after that I can't continue to uninstall additional software because I get a pop up with the message: "Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed".

I guess the problem is that Windows detects that new program I executed from the uninstaller and thinks the uninstallation process is still running.

Anybody knows how to overcome this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does this to deal with old broken uninstallers and it is by design. You could try to [escape the job](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Escape_ARP_Job_With_New_Process) but I don't know if that code works on every version of Windows...

Comment: This actually works fine for XP thanks !
Do you happen to know how I can find the name of the ARP Job in Vista/Win7 ?

Comment: Thanks ! 
Now I see it, but it's an unnamed job :/
Any suggestions on how to proceed then ? How can I still get this job  and change it ?

Comment: There is no documented way to do it IIRC. I don't think a process in a job can open its owning job without knowing the name, a shame really...

Comment: Thanks for your replies Anders. Another option that I came up with is using Windows task scheduler. Just before the uninstaller quits I create a task to be executed several seconds from now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for fixing the registry,

[Mircosoft Fix it](http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall)
[Another such interesting url](http://raywoodcockslatest.blogspot.sg/2011/04/windows-7-wait-until-current-program-is.html)